# Spontaneous scrolling issue macro slow down only on new/newly saved Macro Enabled workbook/template

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Macro Enabled template used for generating end user proposals/estimates. This template references data sets on a shared drive to automatically generate item cost based on various factors.

Two issues has suddenly developed on the first and main tab that I presume are related.

My macros  now spontaneously take 20 times as long to execute. There are few macros of principle concern. One that adds a single row each to the bottom of 3 tables and the other adds 10 rows to the bottom of each table and one that removes a row. These use to zip and not flow like molasses.

The other issue is I can no longer scroll up and down with my mouse wheel. The horizontal scroll wheel works just not up and down. This only effects the first tab. I have Google-fu'd and attempted most obvious solutions to no effect.

Both these issues manifested together. They only effect work books from a  the newest version other the template. If I open an older template it works fine until I save. Then the slows down too.

Does not seem like this is an issue wit the macros themselves. Other macros on other tabs work as anticipated. Regardless below are the macros in question. Again, the macros operate without error. They just all of a sudden take much longer.

I am using Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2206 Build 16.0.15330.20260) 64-bit

```
Sub ADD1ROW()

Sheets("Office").ListObjects("Table1").ListRows.Add AlwaysInsert:=True
Sheets("Builder").ListObjects("Table2").ListRows.Add AlwaysInsert:=True
Sheets("Cost Analysis").ListObjects("Table3").ListRows.Add AlwaysInsert:=True
             
End Sub
```

```
Sub ADD10ROWS()

Dim i As Byte
For i = 1 To 10
Sheets("Office").ListObjects("Table1").ListRows.Add AlwaysInsert:=True
Sheets("Builder").ListObjects("Table2").ListRows.Add AlwaysInsert:=True
Sheets("Cost Analysis").ListObjects("Table3").ListRows.Add AlwaysInsert:=True
Next i
        
End Sub
```

```
Sub REMOVE1ROW()

Dim ans As Long
    With Sheets("Office").ListObjects("Table1").Range
        ans = .Rows.Count
        .Rows(ans).Delete
    End With
    
    With Sheets("Builder").ListObjects("Table2").Range
        ans = .Rows.Count
        .Rows(ans).Delete
    End With
    
    With Sheets("Cost Analysis").ListObjects("Table3").Range
        ans = .Rows.Count
        .Rows(ans).Delete
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Try setting `Application.Screenupdating = False` before adding/removing rows

Comment: Unfortunately that has no effect.